# Why does Ruby raise error for last undefined variable on line?

Tags: ruby, interpreter, operator-precedence

Assuming that `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` have not been defined, the line

`foo bar baz`

raises this error:

`` NameError (undefined local variable or method `baz' for main:Object) ``

In REPLs for Python, PHP, and Javascript the first issue in `foo(bar(baz))` is that `foo` is not defined. Why does Ruby complain about `baz` first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby allows the first method invoked (`baz`) to dynamically define the other two methods. It doesn't attempt to resolve `foo` or `bar` as method invocations until the actual method invocation happens, and it never reaches that method invocation as `baz` first causes an error.

If `baz` dynamically defines the methods `foo` and `bar`, there is no problem:

```
def baz
  define_method(:foo) { |x| "foo #{x}" }
  define_method(:bar) { |x| "bar #{x}" }
  "baz!"
end

foo bar baz # => "foo bar baz!"
```

Comment: The better question, then, is why don't JavaScript et al do the same thing?

Comment: @JordanRunning Differences in how the languages are parsed and evaluated, you'd have to ask somebody with a deeper understanding of both languages why Ruby chooses to allow this while JavaScript doesn't.

Comment: @meagar "Ruby allows the first method invoked (`baz`) to dynamically define the other two methods." This doesn't seem quite right imo. Ruby doesn't define methods automatically, but instead resolves parameters before resolving the method itself. Otherwise you would be able to call `foo` after the error was raised.

Comment: @JohanWentholt I'm not sure what you disagree with. I'm not claiming Ruby defines methods dynamically, I'm saying that methods *can be* defined dynamically, after parsing but before execution. The code in my answer demonstrates this.

Comment: The question is why `baz` gets evaluated first, not whether it can define the other two methods (you could have also defined `bar` and `baz` in `foo`, if `foo` were to evaluate first). This answer is basically just proving what the OP already noticed, not giving an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Ref this post [`ruby-magic-code-interpretation`](https://blog.appsignal.com/2017/08/01/ruby-magic-code-interpretation.html)

& check it in console

```
2.3.1 :001 > puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile("foo bar baz").disasm
== disasm: #<ISeq:<compiled>@<compiled>>================================
0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
0002 putself          
0003 putself          
0004 putself          
0005 opt_send_without_block <callinfo!mid:baz, argc:0, FCALL|VCALL|ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
0008 opt_send_without_block <callinfo!mid:bar, argc:1, FCALL|ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
0011 opt_send_without_block <callinfo!mid:foo, argc:1, FCALL|ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
0014 leave            
 => nil
```

As ruby interpreter order this way it throws the error

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `baz' for main:Object)
```

Comment: I didn't know this technique before now. :)